# ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 0000000027f1cd97 (20200528/exresop-66)

Tags: kernel, acpi, dmesg

```
[ 1489.465625] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 0000000038987839 (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 1489.465633] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 1489.465648] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q80]:
[ 1489.465649]   Local0: 00000000aa0dfae9 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 1489.465653] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q80]
[ 1489.465654] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q80 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 1489.621625] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 0000000027f1cd97 (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 1489.621635] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 1489.621649] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q80]:
[ 1489.621650]   Local0: 0000000037b6ce08 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 1489.621654] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q80]
[ 1489.621656] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q80 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 1489.769621] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 00000000f4e97d31 (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 1489.769630] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 1489.769645] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q80]:
[ 1489.769646]   Local0: 00000000564cff05 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 1489.769650] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q80]
[ 1489.769653] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q80 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 1489.917638] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 00000000339b0355 (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 1489.917647] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 1489.917661] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q80]:
[ 1489.917661]   Local0: 00000000a99324cd <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 1489.917665] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q80]
[ 1489.917667] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q80 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 1490.057632] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 00000000c628cfcb (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 1490.057639] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 1490.057652] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q80]:
[ 1490.057653]   Local0: 00000000d846baea <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 1490.057657] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q80]
[ 1490.057658] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q80 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 1490.181641] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 0000000041583b12 (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 1490.181649] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 1490.181663] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q80]:
[ 1490.181663]   Local0: 00000000697ea599 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 1490.181667] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q80]
[ 1490.181669] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q80 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 1490.373632] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 0000000039c05c82 (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 1490.373640] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 1490.373654] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q80]:
[ 1490.373654]   Local0: 00000000efa964ca <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 1490.373658] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q80]
[ 1490.373659] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q80 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 1490.585610] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 00000000e564932d (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 1490.585618] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 1490.585631] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q80]:
[ 1490.585631]   Local0: 00000000ba2b38b8 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 1490.585635] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q80]
[ 1490.585636] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q80 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 2242.359366] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 00000000888bb010 (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 2242.359379] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 2242.359417] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q81]:
[ 2242.359419]   Local0: 0000000075360f15 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 2242.359429] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q81]
[ 2242.359434] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q81 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 2242.514949] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 00000000c0a8dad4 (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 2242.514955] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 2242.514969] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q81]:
[ 2242.514970]   Local0: 00000000c628cfcb <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 2242.514974] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q81]
[ 2242.514975] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q81 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 2242.659432] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 00000000ea5f0faf (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 2242.659445] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 2242.659476] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q81]:
[ 2242.659478]   Local0: 00000000b710fd63 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 2242.659486] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q81]
[ 2242.659490] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q81 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 2242.799415] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 000000002bcef754 (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 2242.799428] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 2242.799460] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q81]:
[ 2242.799461]   Local0: 0000000097488770 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 2242.799469] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q81]
[ 2242.799473] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q81 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 2242.923452] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 00000000a8305eb5 (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 2242.923464] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 2242.923496] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q81]:
[ 2242.923497]   Local0: 00000000509faf60 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 2242.923505] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q81]
[ 2242.923509] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q81 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 2243.167419] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 000000005c46c214 (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 2243.167431] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 2243.167462] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q81]:
[ 2243.167464]   Local0: 00000000ec7e60fa <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 2243.167472] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q81]
[ 2243.167476] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q81 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 2243.319470] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 00000000edf57ffc (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 2243.319483] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 2243.319515] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q81]:
[ 2243.319517]   Local0: 00000000b07fabc8 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 2243.319525] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q81]
[ 2243.319529] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q81 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 2243.447336] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 000000000da1e18a (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 2243.447349] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 2243.447378] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q81]:
[ 2243.447380]   Local0: 000000009cc1ae9a <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 2243.447388] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q81]
[ 2243.447392] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q81 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 2244.151388] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 00000000f44bb747 (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 2244.151400] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 2244.151429] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q81]:
[ 2244.151431]   Local0: 000000002801aac0 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 2244.151438] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q81]
[ 2244.151442] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q81 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
[ 2245.555375] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Package] 00000000d87977f4 (20200528/exresop-66)
[ 2245.555389] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Notify] (20200528/dswexec-431)
[ 2245.555427] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [_Q80]:
[ 2245.555429]   Local0: 000000001bc2f27f <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[ 2245.555439] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q80]
[ 2245.555444] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q80 due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20200528/psparse-529)
```

Getting this error when I am running CSGO in Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 LTS. I am not able to understand what is the cause behind it?

Comment: Likely a firmware (BIOS or UEFI) problem. Update it before anything else.

Comment: I have checked all the settings but it is not fixing.

Comment: Everything is working fine but when I play CSGO this error comes and in game I am facing shutter when this error arise.